# how do I keep track of the number of inputs for a while loop in python?

Tags: python, random, input, while-loop, range

I'm trying to make a "number guessing game" in python, and I want it to display the number of guesses the user had to make in order to guess the random number generated by the computer at the end. Here's what I have so far to give an example of what I mean:

```
    from random import*
a=randrange(1,51)
b=int(input("Can you guess my number?: "))
while a>b:
    b=int(input("Too low, try again: "))
while a<b:
    b=int(input("Too high, try again: "))
while a==b:
    print("You got it! The number was", a)
    break
```

I'd like it to print something like "it took you __ guesses" at the end. How would I go about keeping track of the number of inputs like that? I tried searching around, but I wasn't really sure how to put it into words.

Comment: First of all, this code doesn't do what you want it to do. Suppose you enter a number that is too low, then a number that is too high, then finally a number that is too low. Your code will terminate prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is get rid of the 3 `while` loops, and change them to `if` statements within a `while` loop:

```
from random import*
a=randrange(1,51)
b = 0
guesses = 0 #Initialize a variable to store how many guesses the user has used
while b != a:
    b=int(input("Can you guess my number?: "))
    if a>b:
        b=int(input("Too low, try again: "))
    else:
        b=int(input("Too high, try again: "))
    guesses+=1

print("You got it! The number was", a)
print("You took {} guesses!".format(guesses))
```

Answer (score 1):

**guess** keeps track of no. of guesses

```
from random import*

a=randrange(1,51)
guess = 0
while True:
    b=int(input("Can you guess my number?: "))
    guess += 1

    if b==a:
        print("You got it correct")
        break

    elif b>a:
        print("number is higher")

    else:
        print("number is lower")

print("Guesses: ", guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

> d = 74
>   count = 1

`def check(n):
    if n==d:
        count += 1
        print "You Got the number"
    elif n>d:

        print "The number is too high"
        count += 1
        check(int(raw_input('Enter another number')))
    elif n<d:

        print "The no is too low"
        if count
        count += 1
        check(int(raw_input('Enter something high')))
    return count`

The value returned is the number of guesses